# How to connect to Router Admin Panel that is connected to other router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

So in easy way my two routers are in this configuration:

[image]

and these are settings from R1, I thouh i would be able to connect to R2 by 192.168.0.3 but with not success
[image]

I want to connect from PC1 to admin page of R2, When i am using 192.168.01 I am connected to router R1, but if PC would be connected to R2 then I would be in settings of R2. How I can connect from PC1 to R2 by IP adress? How I can get that IP adress? (all masks are standard 255.255.255.0)

Connection was LAN_LAN

Comment: From user [Svetozar Miuchin](http://superuser.com/users/557849/svetozar-miuchin): Try:[some explanation to configure network](http://portforward.com/help/doublerouterportforwarding.htm)

Comment: Have you tried setting the other router outside your network range say Change the settings in the first router to using router as a dhcp server to use ip range 192.168.0.1 as the start and the end to use 192.168.0.200 on router 2 uncheck us a dhcp server. and use  192.168.0.201 as your ip on the router. and then you should be able to access it.

Comment: What kind of device is R2?  If it is not a plain router but has a WAN and a LAN side then you probably connected the cable to the WAN port, which typically has remote manaement disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure router R1 is in bridge mode
2. Router R2 is forwarding all DHCP requests to R1
3. R2 has a static ip
4. Connect to R2 from PC1 make sure you are able to ping R1 and then vice Versa
5. Disable DHCP on the R2 router

I think the key here is your Lan mode

Comment: I let myselft to add 5th step :) thx for help

Comment: Glad it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you connect to R2 from the "outside", and possibly your router doesn't allow this (usual default configuration).